# What is this shape called? It's a circle with a right angle in one corner

Tags: shapes, terminology

I'm trying to find an example of this shape online, but I don't know what to look for. It seems to be pretty popular in graphic design lately. It's a circle with a right angle in one corner. But when I search for that nothing comes up.

Thank you ahead of time!!

[image]

Comment: Uhm...I don't think this has a name :)) it's just a circle with a 90 degrees corner. That's all there is to it..

Comment: Map pin, leaf, drop

Comment: Overloaded ice cream cone?

Comment: Minimalist speech bubble... maybe modern speech bubble. Post-modern really. Post Post-Modern Speech Bubble

Comment: Lol I love the post post-modern speech bubble.

Comment: Distance urinal.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it most closely resembles a **teardrop shape**. That's what it's referred to as within Microsoft PowerPoint:

[image: PowerPoint screenshot]

<sup>Screenshot courtesy of [indezine.com](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/fillslinesandeffects/no-fill-in-powerpoint-2011.html)</sup>

Photoshop has a similar (yet not exactly the same) shape, they call it a **raindrop**.

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

Answer (score -4):

A squircle and it's a real word.

Comment: Yes a squircle is a real thing. but no.. the shape in the question bears *zero* resemblance to a squircle. It is most definitely *not* a [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).